# Trigger in oracle

Tags: triggers, oracle10g, sql-update

**account**

```
----------
accno varchar

acctotal number
```

**student**

```
----------
id varchar

fees number

accno varchar
```

I want to create a **trigger** which **updates 'account' table** anytime a record is **deleted from 'student'**.
It subtracts fees of student from acctotal in account.

thnx in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER account_after_delete
AFTER DELETE
   ON student
   FOR EACH ROW

BEGIN

  UPDATE account SET acctotal=acctotal -:old.fees 
  WHERE accno=:old.accno;

END;
```